# What are the iPhone SE size?

Tags: display, iphone

I am looking to buy an iPhone SE but this is my first time, I've never used an iPhone and I want to know that the new iPhone is of 4" so what does the 4" mean?

The DISPLAY size or the whole BODY size is 4"? It will be a great help if anyone could help me! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the information you are asking are reported in the [specification page of Apple](http://www.apple.com/iphone-se/specs/) for iPhone SE.

In particular, the display is 4 inch display, while the other dimensions are reported in the following pic.
[image]